# How to provide 3 options (pull-up, pull down and Open) in an IC

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, pullup, deserialiser

I have [MAX9278](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9278-MAX9282.pdf) Deserializer IC.

I have 2 doubts.

Doubts :

1. I am performing the schematic now. Below, I need to provide options for both 24-bit, 27-bit and 32-bit.

[image]

How to provide the provision for all three modes? Pull-up, Pull-down and Open?

2. What should do with unused pins?

Comment: For 1) so what is the exact question, how to leave pin open? For 2) would you specify which unused pins, which pins are you going to use and which pins not?

Comment: 1. I want to be able use the pin in 3 different modes at different times. Is it possible? 2. I am planning to un-use the GPIO pins and the I2S pins.

Comment: Read page 61, _"3-Level Configuration Inputs... Connect 3-level inputs through a pullup resistor to IOVDD to set a high level, a pulldown resistor to GND to set a low
level, or open to set a mid level. For digital control, use three-state logic to drive the 3-level logic input."_

Comment: Could you tell me how to create a three-state logic ?

Comment: What do you plan to use as an input to the logic? Jumpers, digital signals, anything else?

Comment: Maxim is just telling you that the internal logic detects three states. That pin selects the bus bandwidth, normally you just pick one and wire it up directly. But if you wanted to support all three possible configurations (a bit more complicated), just connect a GPIO pin to drive it. Drive it high to signal logic high, drive it low to signal logic low, and leave it undriven (GPIO configured as input) to leave it in the third state.  Or copy the EV kit schematic? (*I am a Maxim applications engineer, and I think I recognize this particular EV kit as one I worked on several years ago*).